# Servicestack serverless example - authenticated services fail

Tags: authentication, cookies, servicestack

We are trying to send another coder an example web page which contains javascript that authenticates to our ServiceStack service and then runs a sample service. That code fails when run in Chrome and I believe it's because the auth cookies are not being set properly (the Auth service works, but the second, authenticated service returns a 401). It looks like Chrome discards cookies in "serverless" web pages. Is there a way we can get the example to work properly?

```
Response headers of auth:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/5.02 NET45 Win32NT/.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: ss-id=P50BQ7hjt9SVLUWBzg3a; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: ss-pid=NaswTwDxcaDAj485XuSE; expires=Sun, 14-Feb-2038 13:04:20 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: ss-opt=temp; expires=Sun, 14-Feb-2038 13:04:20 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Feb 2018 13:04:21 GMT
Content-Length: 267

Request headers of subsequent service (returns an .mp4 file):
GET /svc/VidClip/20171000272/1/245/0/1/H080301.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: null
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Range: bytes=0-

Response Headers (note the ss-pid and ss-id do not match):
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: DV realm="/auth/credentials"
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/5.02 NET45 Win32NT/.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: ss-pid=RKC1hyQc1ePk1gF50WOB; expires=Sun, 14-Feb-2038 13:04:21 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: ss-id=zYtKpO6WpuTDx49LNgsW; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Feb 2018 13:04:21 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Vid Test - localhost</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var basic = new Object();
            basic.username = 'xxxxxxx';
            basic.password = 'yyyyyyy';

            $('button').off('click').on('click', function (_e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/svc/auth',
                    data: JSON.stringify(basic),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    accept: 'application/json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                }).done(function(_d){
            $('video').attr('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            $('video').attr('src', 'http://localhost/svc/VidClip/20171000272/1/245/0/1/H080301.mp4');
                    $('video')[0].play();
                }).fail(function(_err){
                    console.log(_err);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button>Click me!</button>
    <div class="video">
        <video></video>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what "serverless" technology you're using, e.g. are you referring to ServiceStack running in AWS lambda, Azure functions or GCP Cloud functions? Can you also update your question to include the client code you're using + the raw HTTP Headers of the Authentication Request + subsequent request to the Service (scrubbing out any sensitive info with xxxx)

Comment: Sorry, servicestack itself is on an IIS Web Server - what I mean to say is that the sample web page itself is not on web server, I am loading it into my browser from my Windows desktop, meaning the url in the browser is file:///C:/Users/mtagliaf/Desktop/test.html. Service call headers added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the HTTP Request doesn't contain the Cookies returned from the Authentication Request. There's extra security restrictions from .html pages loaded from the local file system, previously you could open chrome.exe with the `--enable-file-cookies` flag but that has [since been removed](https://codereview.chromium.org/976553002) so you would need server the .html file from a local HTTP Server (e.g. `http://127.0.0.1/test.html`) for Cookies to be included in ajax requests.